# cant import an exported file into wampserver

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a database, linked it to project and even inserted some values in them. nothing seemed wrong. but after I exported the file. and later decided to import it into wamp, I get this error message:

```
Error

SQL query: 


--
-- Database: `dimensioncon`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `admission_form`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `admission_form`



MySQL said: Documentation 
#1046 - No database selected
```

please what seems to be the problem? and how do I import the database back please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use dimensioncon; --your database name
```

Then use your SQL query

SQL query:

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `admission_form`

--
-- Table structure for table `admission_form`
```

--

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `USE dimensioncon;` in the starting of your exported file

Something like

```
USE Your_Database_Name;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admission_form` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10001 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `admission_form`
--

INSERT INTO `admission_form` (`user_id`, `username`) VALUES (1, 'rogers63');
```

Answer (score 0):

first use 'Database Name';

```
use dimensioncon;
```

SQL query:

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `admission_form`;
```

and now imported your sql file.